# How to expand the google logo on google's home page?

Tags: javascript

I want to expand the google logo on google's home page every second using `setInterval()`. I've been trying some stuff out in the chrome JS console but none of them worked, like:

```
function expander(logo) {
    logo.style.width = "100px";
    logo.style.width += "100px";
}
setInterval(expander(document.querySelector("#hplogo")), 1000);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: "+" perform operation on numeric value.
This statement is wrong on your function:

logo.style.width += "100px";

Instead of this, you should have something like this:

logo.style.width = (interval * 100)+ "px";

Increase the interval everytime you call the function and it will set the width.
Also remove the first line of function.

Comment: You have good answers down there, but none explain *why* your code doesn't work: `setInterval` wants the **name** of the function as its first parameter (it is called a *callback*). You could call `setInterval(expander, 1000)`, but not with parentheses and parameters. You can also wrap that in an anonymous function: `setInterval(function(){expander(document.querySelector("#hplogo"))}, 1000)`, that also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
val = 1; 
logo = document.querySelector("#hplogo")
setInterval(
    function(){ 
       logo.style.width = (val * 100) + "px"; 
       val = val + 1; 
    },
1000);
```

As per SteeveDroz's comment:

> `setInterval` wants the name of the function as its first parameter (it is called a callback). You could call `setInterval(expander, 1000)`, but not with parentheses and parameters. You can also wrap that in an anonymous function as this answer does.

Comment: I think this answer should have more of an explanation as to why it works and the original does not. ie sending the function as a parameter vs executing the function.

Comment: You can freely reuse my comment of the question if you want!